# do cronbach and factor analysis work together

Tags: regression, correlation, factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor, cronbachs-alpha

I am writing a Master's Thesis based on a four construct model. I know I have to conduct a Cronbach's alpha test for reliability and I also need to conduct a confirmatory factor analysis for validity of constructs prior to conducting the correlation and regression analyses between the constructs. But I have a few questions: 
1.) Does it matter which I do first, Cronbach's alpha or factor analysis, do they affect each other. For instance, if I do Cronbach's first and determine one of the items is below 0.7 and I remove it, do I then not include it in the factor analysis, and vice versa if I were to conduct the factor analysis first and then Cronbach's?

2.) If the Cronbach's alpha is already .7 or greater, but removing an item will make it even greater, should I? or will removing items keep making the alpha higher?

3.) After I do conduct both of the preliminary tests and move on to my correlation and regression, how do I summarize the different items to test the constructs against each other. For instance, I have one 10 item construct that I want to determine the correlation with a 15 item construct. What do I take to summarize them to run them together/against each other to determine correlation and regression.

Thank you for your help, I am teaching myself a lot of this stuff and have been mostly confused, so any insight and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to search `cronbach alpha factor analysis` on the site?

Comment: Yes, I've looked at all the site has on the two...and some people have asked similar questions but without getting full or helpful answers in return